# Bootstrap's Help Block with icon messes up the form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I am using css from this [**Bootsnip**](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/support-glyph-and-fa-icon-inside-input) and it is working well, however, when I try to add a help block with icon, it does not work as expected.

Help block w/o icon (added following code after input):

```
<label class="help-block">* Required Field</label>
```

[image]

Help block w/ icon (added following code after input):

```
<label class="help-block glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign">* Required Field</label>
```

[image]

Inside the css, it does clear the float, so not sure why it is still messing up.

```
.icon-addon:after { clear: both; }
```

Comment: I do not understand. I forked the bootsnip and it works fine

Comment: @DaMaxContent My code (provided above) is not in Bootsnipp link since I do not have an account there, so the code above must be added manually to the html portion.

Comment: look at my answer. I found the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You are placing the label, right after the input field. This is wrong. You need to place the label after the `<div class="icon-addon ... " ... > ... </div>` element.

To show you: ([**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t2stkygL/1/))

```css
.center-block {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.input-group .icon-addon .form-control {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.icon-addon {
    position: relative;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
}

.icon-addon:after,
.icon-addon:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}

.icon-addon:after {
    clear: both;
}

.icon-addon.addon-md .glyphicon,
.icon-addon .glyphicon, 
.icon-addon.addon-md .fa,
.icon-addon .fa {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: -2.5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    top: 1px
}

.icon-addon.addon-lg .form-control {
    line-height: 1.33;
    height: 46px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 16px 10px 40px;
}

.icon-addon.addon-sm .form-control {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 28px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.icon-addon.addon-lg .fa,
.icon-addon.addon-lg .glyphicon {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 0;
    left: 11px;
    top: 4px;
}

.icon-addon.addon-md .form-control,
.icon-addon .form-control {
    padding-left: 30px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.icon-addon.addon-sm .fa,
.icon-addon.addon-sm .glyphicon {
    margin-left: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 5px;
    top: -1px
}

.icon-addon .form-control:focus + .glyphicon,
.icon-addon:hover .glyphicon,
.icon-addon .form-control:focus + .fa,
.icon-addon:hover .fa {
    color: #2580db;
}
```

```html
<!--LIBRARIES USED BY BOOTSNIP:-->
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--REQUIRED LIBRARY USED BY BOOTSNIP:-->
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="icon-addon addon-lg">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="email"><label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="email"></label>
  </div>
  
  <!--HERE:-->
  <!--HERE:-->

  <div align="left">
    <label class="help-block glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign">*<span style="font-family:Arial"> This is a Required Field (align="left")</span></label>
  </div>
  
  <!--HERE:-->
  <!--HERE:-->
  
  <div class="icon-addon addon-lg">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="email"><label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="email"></label>
  </div>
  
  <!--HERE:-->
  <!--HERE:-->

  <div align="center">
    <label class="help-block glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign">*<span style="font-family:Arial"> This is a Required Field (align="center")</span></label>
  </div>
  
  <!--HERE:-->
  <!--HERE:-->
  
  <div class="icon-addon addon-lg">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="email">

    <!--NOT HERE:-->
    <!--NOT HERE:-->
    <!--NOT HERE:-->
    
    <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="email"></label>
  </div>
  
  <!--HERE:-->
  <!--HERE:-->

  <div align="right">
    <label class="help-block glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign">*<span style="font-family:Arial"> This is a Required Field (align="right")</span></label>
  </div>
  
  <!--HERE:-->
  <!--HERE:-->
  
</div>
```

Comment: When I tried that, it wasn't working properly for me, but it appears to be working now. However, the label text seems like it is set to form-control since it is stretched out. https://jsfiddle.net/ishq786/t2stkygL/4/ Also, if there are more input fields below, it becomes messy again when the help block is set to pull right: https://jsfiddle.net/ishq786/t2stkygL/5/

Comment: @Ali Fixed the code. For that case, you need to nest the label in a div to adjust alignment properties (`align="right"` for example). You also need to add a span with its own font (I used `Arial`, because the spacing is due to the font the bootsnip uses.

Comment: Align right did the trick! Any idea why the * is appearing the way it is? Is it just how help-block handles it or another reason? Will accept your answer soon.

Comment: yes. It is the font style: 'Glyphicons Halflings'. that font is also the reason for the awkward word spacing. It is what makes the icons possible. It shouldn't be used for normal text, apparantly. I left the * with the font, because I thought it looked nice

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the help! What was the reason for the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

this could help

```
<label class="help-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>* Required Field</label>
```